# $ | \;\overline{z_1}^{3-\alpha} z_1^\alpha - \overline{z_2}^{3-\alpha} z_2 ^\alpha | \leq ( |z_1 - z_2 |^2 + |z_2| ^2 )|z_1 - z_2|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

For $\alpha = 0,1,2,3$, does this inequality always hold for any complex number $z_1, z_2$? $$ | \;\overline{z_1}^{3-\alpha} z_1^\alpha - \overline{z_2}^{3-\alpha} z_2 ^\alpha | \leq ( |z_1 - z_2 |^2 + |z_2| ^2 )|z_1 - z_2|$$
$\overline{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality does not hold in the reals. Let $z_1=2$ and $z_2=1$.

Comment: It think the case $z_1 = 2, z_2 = 0$ hold..

Comment: Sorry, typo. It was $z_2=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! p.s. I wrote a new question for weaker version: $ | \;\overline{z_1}^{3-\alpha} z_1^\alpha - \overline{z_2}^{3-\alpha} z_2 ^\alpha | \leq C ( |z_1 - z_2 |^2 + |z_2| ^2 )|z_1 - z_2|$